# Protecting / escaping the # (number-sign/hash) in a callable macro?

Tags: macros, tex-core

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

% \gdef\myset{  %*
\tikzset{ %
  mystyle/.style={rectangle},
  mycode/.code n args={2}{%
    \typeout{YEAH! #1 #2} %
  },
} % end tikzset
% } % end gdef  %*


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% \myset        %*

\node[mystyle,mycode={trying}{out}] (origin) at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you compile it as is, it will print "`YEAH! trying out`" to stdout. However, if you uncomment the lines marked with `%*`, then compilation fails with:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \myset.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.9     \typeout{YEAH! #1
                          #2} %
?
```

... clearly, because Latex thinks the `#1` is for the `\gdef\myset`, while I intend it to be for the `\tikzset{` command inside it!

So, after checking out [How to get the catcode of a token?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21367/how-to-get-the-catcode-of-a-token), and doing `texdef -t latex \makeatletter` and `texdef -t latex \makeatother`, and `` \typeout{catcode of #: \the\catcode`#} ``, I came up with the following analog to `\makeatletter`, called `\makehashletter`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\typeout{catcode of #: \the\catcode`#} %catcode of ##: 6
\def\makehashletter{\catcode`\#11\relax}
\def\makehashother{\catcode`\#6\relax}

\makehashletter
\gdef\myset{  %*
\tikzset{ %
  mystyle/.style={rectangle},
  mycode/.code n args={2}{%
    \typeout{YEAH! #1 #2} %
  },
} % end tikzset
} % end gdef  %*
\makehashother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\myset        %*

\node[mystyle,mycode={trying}{out}] (origin) at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

... and this does compile - but it dumps `YEAH! #1 #2` to stdout, which is not what I intended.

So my question is - is there a way to protect the `#` in a macro like the above, such that when the macro is ran and calls `tikzset`, the `tikzset` will see the previously protected `#`s as arguments?

Would it also be possible to somehow use that protection only on certain arguments (e.g. `\myset` could itself accept `#1`, which I would use "unprotected"; and I'd protect/escape the `tikzset` specific ones )?

(Note that I've tried:

```
\edef\hashmark{\string#}
```

... as in [Match number sign inside plain TeX loop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88139/match-number-sign-inside-plain-tex-loop/88150#88150), and then using `\hashmark1` instead of `#1` where I want them "escaped", but that didn't work)

Comment: Double your hash symbols: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42463/what-is-the-meaning-of-double-pound-symbol-1-in-an-argument

Comment: Thanks, @JosephWright - I've seen that before, but forgot about it; this post can now serve as reminder `:)` Cheers!